# How to style the CSS bootstrap 'col' elements?

Tags: python, html, css, django, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to style bootstrap CSS columns col-xl so that I'll be able to have 5 or 6 cards/tiles on my page instead of 4 (page image attached) without touching the other grid layouts. However at this point I've no idea on how to achieve that. Below is my code:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load static %}



{% block content %}
  <h2>My Meals</h2>

  <div class='py-4 mt-auto'>
    <div class='container px-4'>

      <div class="row meal-tiles">
        {% for meal in meals %}
          <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 d-flex align-items-stretch meal-tile">
            <div class="card mb-3 meal-tile-border">
                {% if meal.image %}
                  <img src="{{ meal.image.url }}" alt="{{ meal.name }}" class="img-fluid" style="height: 200px;">
                {% else %}
                  <img src="{% static 'images/mealdefault.png' %}" alt="Default Image" class="img-fluid" style="height: 200px;">
                {% endif %}

              <div class="card-body">

                <h4 class='card-title'> <strong>{{ meal.name }}</strong></h4>
                {% with macros=meal.calculate_total_macros %}
                  <p>Kcal in 100g: {{ macros.total_kcal_per_100g }}</p>
                  <p>Carbohydrates in 100g: {{ macros.total_carbohydrates_per_100g }}</p>
                  <p>Fats in 100g: {{ macros.total_fats_per_100g }}</p>
                  <p>Proteins in 100g: {{ macros.total_proteins_per_100g }}</p>
                  <p>Glycemic Load in 100g: {{ macros.total_glycemic_load_per_100g }}</p>
                  <p>Glycemic Index: {{ macros.average_glycemic_index }}</p>
                {% endwith %}
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
        {% empty %}
          <div class="col-12">
            <p>No meals found.</p>
          </div>
        {% endfor %}
      </div>


    </div>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

I've tried styling the css for the .col-xl in the main.css file however it didn't work well. If I try just styling margins then it's set for all the other layouts which are fine and I don't really want to touch them

What i tried in the main.css file:
  `.col-xl { margin-left: 20px; margin-right: 20px; }`

[image: page tiles]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get this correct, you want to style the col only on at this exact code.

Have you tried something like `.meal-tile.col-xl-3 { margin-left: 20px; margin-right: 20px; }`?

If you add the `.meal-tile` direktly to the `col-xl` (no space) you speify the scope exactly to this element.

Comment: When I add that lines of code the margin is unfortunately still starting as in the picture so it only results into the tiles moving to the next row

Comment: So you want to use more space on a bigger screen? Then you might want to set the bootstrap screen breakpoint via sass: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/breakpoints/ or use container-fluid on this page (maybe with some grind around) to use the hole width of the screen https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/containers/#how-they-work